# D3 GeoJson Choropleth and different data files loading depending on onClick Button

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I want to create a choropleth showing data of production of different animals. Depending on an `onClick`-Event Button I want to load different files of data to create the colorpleth. I have 4 different JSON-files for sheep, pig, chick and cows. First I'm loading the map data in europe.json and then the data from chick.json/cow.json/sheep.json/pig.json. In the different for-loops I'm summing up numbers to get the total for all years per country.
I tried different approaches to create 4 buttons and depending on the clicks to load one of the 4 JSON data files and read all stackoverflow questions with similar questions but my project is a bit different because of the choropleth.

the JSONs with data look like this:

```
[{
"2005": 0,
"2006": 0,
"2007": 0,
"2008": 0,
"2009": 0,
"2010": 0,
"2011": 0,
"2012": 0,
"2013": 0,
"2014": 0,
"2015": 3.26,
"2016": 2.27,
"geo": "AL",
"fleischart": "sheep"
},
{ 
"2005": 7.15,
"2006": 0,
"2007": 0,
"2008": 8.22,
"2009": 7.87,
"2010": 8.03,
"2011": 8.35,
"2012": 8.37,
"2013": 8.45,
"2014": 7.98,
"2015": 7.77,
"2016": 7.3,
"geo": "AT",
"fleischart": "sheep"
 }, { ....
```

different objects for different countries.
and my code looks like this:

```
<div id="container">
 </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var w = 800;
var h = 600;
var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
    .center([ 13, 52 ])
    .translate([ w/2, h/2 ])
    .scale([ w/1.5 ]);

 var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var svg = d3.select("#container")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

 d3.json("europe.json", function (json) {
    console.log(json);
     d3.json("chick.json", function (error, data) {
         if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log(data);
            dataset = data;
        }

        var mengeprojahrproland = new Array();
        var mengedurchschnittproland = new Array;
        for (var n = 0; n < 36; n++) {
            var landName = Object(data[n])["geo"];
            var total = 0;
            mengeprojahrproland.push(Object.values(data[n]));

            for (var q = 0; q < 12; q++) {
                total += Object(mengeprojahrproland[n])[q];
            }
                 mengedurchschnittproland.push(parseFloat(total).toFixed(2));

            var landmengeobjekt = [{Land: 0, Anzahl: 0}];
            var laender = [];
            var laendermenge = [];

            for (var m = 0; m < 36; m++) {
                var landName = Object(data[m])["geo"];
                var durchschnittmengeprojahr = mengedurchschnittproland[m];
                laender.push(landName);
                laendermenge.push(durchschnittmengeprojahr);
                landmengeobjekt.push({Land: landName, Anzahl: durchschnittmengeprojahr});
            }
        }

        for (var a = 0; a < laender.length; a++) {
            var dataState = laender[a];
            var dataValue = parseFloat(laendermenge[a]);
            var color = d3.scale.threshold()
                .domain([
                    1, 2,
                    5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400, 450, 500, 550, 600, 650, 700, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500, 3000, 3500, 4000, 4500, 5000, 6000, 7000, 10000, 11000, 15000, 17500, 18000, 19000, 22000
                ])
                .range([
                    "#2438FF", "#2A36F8", "#3035F1", "#3633EA", "#3C32E3", "#4230DC", "#482FD5", "#4E2ECE", "#542CC7", "#5A2BC0", "#6029B9", "#6628B2", "#6D27AB", "#7325A4", "#79249D", "#7F2296", "#85218F", "#8B1F88", "#911E82", "#971D7B", "#9D1B74", "#A31A6D", "#A91866", "#AF175F", "#B61658", "#BC1451", "#C2134A", "#C81143", "#CE103C", "#D40E35", "#DA0D2E", "#E00C27", "#E60A20", "#EC0919", "#F20712", "#F8060B", "#FF0505"
                ]);

            for (var j = 0; j < json.features.length; j++) {
                var jsonState = json.features[j].properties.wb_a2;
                if (jsonState == dataState) {
                    json.features[j].properties.value = dataValue;

                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        svg.selectAll("path")
            .data(json.features)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("d", path)
            .style("fill", function (d) {
                var value = d.properties.value;
                if (value) {
                    return color(value);
                } else {
                    return "darkgray";
                }
            });
    });
});
```

this is the current choropleth for the chick.json data: insahne.com/colorpleth/indexchick.html
how can I achieve to load different files depending on user's click?

Comment: i think you're gonna need to use a menu selector. we have a similar application for soils in different geographies. we present the selections in a menu and then load the D3+JSON specific to the geography.